# How can I make my hamburger menu button change colors once clicked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap and am trying to have the basic hamburger menu button change background colors once clicked. I can make the color change within the browser when it is inspected, but cannot replicate in my css. I also cannot make the color change only when clicked on. I believe it may be a specificity problem. The hamburger button was taken from one of the bootstrap examples.

The below navbar is coded to show "Food, LLC" in the upper left, and for all of the other links to be hidden until the width is reduced to 769px. The hamburger button appears when the 769px width is hit. The links then appear as drop downs when the button is clicked on.

I am using a background color of red as an example, but any color change will be appreciated!

I have tried to be as specific as possible with the navbar-toggler class to see if I can make it change, but am not able to. This is tested on chrome.

Additionally, I have tried using the ":active" css property with no luck.

```css
@media (min-width: 769px) {
 button {
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
 }

.navbar-brand>.navbar-toggler{
    background-color: red !important;
 }

 .navbar-toggler:active{
    background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-collapse-md navbar-dark bg-dark" 
id="button">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Food, LLC</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" id="navbarToggleExternalContent 
active" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse active" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="color">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="chicken.html">Chicken</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="beef.html">Beef</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="sushi.html">Sushi</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can target the `.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"]` selector if you just want to use CSS without creating any custom classes.

If you inspect the page, thanks to Bootstrap's JS, whenever you click on the button, the `aria-expanded` attribute toggles between `true` and `false`, so you can use this to you advantage.

```css
.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-collapse-md navbar-dark bg-dark" id="button">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Food, LLC</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" id="navbarToggleExternalContent 
active" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse active" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="color">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="chicken.html">Chicken</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="beef.html">Beef</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="sushi.html">Sushi</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This addressed my question quickly and efficiently!

Comment: God bless You! :D

Answer (score 1):

use jquery and toggle active class on click.

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
  .navbar-brand>.navbar-toggler.active{
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to change the icon or the background.

To change the icon this works for me (although active state will be de-selected in a split second):

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon:active {
    background: red !important; // will replace the icon image with a red square
}
```

To change the background:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler:active {
    background: red;
}
```

Ideally a class would toggle on the `.navbar-toggler` on click. E.g. when the user clicks on it `active` will be added. This way it will remain in "active" state unless the page refreshes or something removes it again. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837562/3163075)

You could do something like

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler.active { //note the change from : to .
    background: red;
}
```

Or as [@IvanS95](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837534/3163075) mentioned:

> You can target the `.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"]` selector if
>   you just want to use CSS without creating any custom classes